# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'naam' of undefined

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am making a survey in JS and I'm trying to get "kaas" to display on my page by selecting the 1st option every time but it gives me this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'naam' of undefined"

How can I fix this?

```
    document.write('<form id="form" name="enquete"><p>Zoekt u naar een mobiel product of naar een alles-in-1 pakket?</p><input type="radio" name="naam" id="1">Een mobiel pakket<br><input type="radio" name="naam" id="2">Een alles in 1 pakket<br><input type="radio" name="naam" id="3">Beide<br><br><input type="button" onclick="functie()" value="Submit"></form>');

    function functie() 
    {
        var Instap = 0;
        var Standaard = 0;
        var Premium = 0;
        var Internet = 0;
        var ZInstap = 0;
        var ZStandaard = 0;
        var ZPremium = 0;
        var Budget100 = 0;
        var Budget300 = 0;
        var Basis = 0;
        var VInternetInstap = 0;
        var VInternetStandaard = 0;

        document.getElementById('form').submit();
            for (var i = 0; i < document.enquete.naam.length; i++) 
            {
                if (document.enquete.naam[i].checked) 
                {
                    switch(i)
                    {
                        case 0:
                        {
                        //Mobiel pakket
                        document.write('<form id="form2" name="enquete2"><p>Hoeveel belminuten wilt u per maand?</p><input type="radio" name="naam2" id="1">100<br><input type="radio" name="naam2" id="2">150<br><input type="radio" name="naam2" id="3">200<br><input type="radio" name="naam2" id="4">300<br><input type="radio" name="naam2" id="5">Onbeperkt<br><br><input type="button" onclick="" value="Submit"></form>');
                        //document.getElementById('form2').submit();
                        if (document.enquete2.naam2[i].checked) 
                        {
                        switch(i)
                        {
                            case 0:

                            ZInstap = ZInstap + 1;
                            ZStandaard = ZStandaard +1;
                            ZPremium = ZPremium + 1;
                            document.write("kaas");
                            break;

                            case 1:

                            Basis = Basis + 1;
                            VInternetInstap + 1;
                            break;

                            case 2:

                            VInternetStandaard = VInternetStandaard + 1;
                            break;

                            case 3:

                            Budget300 = Budget300 + 1;
                            break;

                            case 4:

                            ZInstap = ZInstap + 1;
                            ZStandaard = ZStandaard + 1;
                            ZPremium + ZPremium + 1;
                            break;

                        }
                        }
                        }
                        break;
                        /*
                        Standaard = Standaard + 1;
                        Premium = Premium + 1;
                        Internet = Internet + 1;
                        */


                        case 1:
                        {
                        //Alles in 1
                        document.write("Alles in 1");

                        break;
                        }

                        case 2:
                        {
                        //Beide
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: why do you think that **document.enquete.naam** should exist?

Comment: To determine the value for the case selection

Comment: No, I understand what are you trying to do, but I dont think, you can get values of form just like this - document.formName.inputName.attribute. That would be really great if it would work. For something like that i would use jQuery and jQuery selector $('form[name=enquete] input[name=naam]').attr('checked'); I dont know how to do something like this in plain javascript, but I am nearly sure you cant do it the way you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the form by name in the manner you are attempting. Use this.

`var formy = document.forms["enquete"];`

and then change all your "name" tags to class tags.

`var collection = formy.getElementsByClassName('naam')`

and then do your repeater logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you give all the form elements an unique id instead of numbers, you can access the form elements via the object (dot) notation.

here's a small example:

```js
document.write('<form id="form" name="enquete"><p>Zoekt u naar een mobiel product of naar een alles-in-1 pakket?</p><input type="radio" name="naam" id="naam1">Een mobiel pakket<br><input type="radio" name="naam" id="naam2">Een alles in 1 pakket<br><input type="radio" name="naam" id="naam3">Beide<br><br><input type="button" id="send" value="Submit"></form><br/><output id="outText" />');

// here goes the logic
send.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var checkd = (form.naam1.checked) ?
       form.naam1.nextSibling.textContent : (form.naam2.checked) ?
       form.naam2.nextSibling.textContent : (form.naam3.checked) ?
       form.naam3.nextSibling.textContent : "nothing";
  outText.innerText = "checked: " + checkd;
});
```

Comment: I could ahve done that also with simple if statements instead of the () ? : notation, but I thought that this is easier to read.